# How to add a 'buffer' to lines on a mesh?

Tags: modeling

I have 3D mesh here:
[image]

And I would like to add 'buffers' to those lines over the top face.

[image]

What's the best way to go about 'buffering' those lines on the top surface?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add some parallel edges to the existing ones, like a kind of bevel?

Comment: Yeah! If I could add some edges like where those red lines are. That'll be great.

Comment: Kind of... I have attached a picture for you to see what I've got. I would like the 'blue' lines that I've drawn to be the same distance if possible.